# javax.mail.Session with null hostname,port and auth?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using `javax.mail.Session` to configure session for 
`org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl`

while configuring `Session` object, I am passing following properties as blank

1. mail.smtp.auth
2. mail.smtp.host
3. mail.smtp.port

Despite blank properties, I am still able to send mail using `JavaMailSenderImpl`, What default values are being used by `session/JavaMailSenderImpl` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mail.smtp.auth - Attempt to authenticate the user using the AUTH command, if true. Defaults to false
- mail.smtp.host - The SMTP server to connect to
- mail.smtp.port - The SMTP server port to connect to, if the connect() method doesn't explicitly specify one. Defaults to 25

Comment: port could not be `null`, set default.